# Overloading << and >> when using templates

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a Vector template, in its basic version it would look like this:

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
class Vector{

Type _member[Size];

public:
Type operator[] const (int i);
Type& operator[] (int i);       // used to access member, definitions in .cpp file
}
```

I want to be able to run it for double and Complex numbers type, I have Complex defined in my files. And with variable size ofc. Anyway, in main I create a vector like that:

```
Vector<double, 3> V1;
cin << V1;
cout >> V1
```

But I cannot make there overloads work. I'm stuck at it. My overloads without a template were these:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Vector &Vec);
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &Strm, const Vector &Vec);
```

and I have no idea on how to adapt them.

Comment: *"I'm stuck at it."* does **not** explain your problem well.  Why are you stuck? Do you have a compiler error? Does it crash when you try to run it?  Show the code that does not work, and explain what the error is.

Comment: A `Wector` is what? Typedef of some type over `Vector<>` ?

Comment: @Ajay:  Its not a `Wector`, its a `Wektor`!  I imagine it is how [**Pavel Chekov**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Chekov) pronounces "Vector"

Comment: In your last code snippet, I'm guessing `Wektor` was meant to be `Vector`? Otherwise I don't see how class `Wektor` is at all relevant to the rest of the code.

Comment: @Daniel: "My overloads without a template were these"; implying that `Wektor` is a class being replaced by the `Vector` template.

Answer (score 1):

They'll need to be templates:

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Vector<Type, Size> &Vec);
```